# Django CMS - not able to upload images through cmsplugin_filer_image

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms, django-file-upload

i have a problem with a local installation on django cms 2.3.3: i've installed it trough pip, in a separated virtualenv. next i followed the tutorial for settings.py configuration, i started the server. Then in the admin i created an page (home), and i've tried to add an image in the placeholder through the cmsplugin_filer_image, but the upload seems that doesn't work. here's my settings.py:

```
# Django settings for cms1 project.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'cms1',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'cms',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'cms',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Rome'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it-it'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"


# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static_auto"),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '^c2q3d8w)f#gk%5i)(#i*lwt%lm-!2=(*1d!1cf+rg&amp;-hqi_9u'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cms1.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cms1.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates"),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
    ('template_2.html', 'Template Two'),
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)

LANGUAGES = [
    ('it', 'Italiano'),
    ('en', 'English'),
]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cms', #django CMS itself
    'mptt', #utilities for implementing a modified pre-order traversal tree
    'menus', #helper for model independent hierarchical website navigation
    'south', #intelligent schema and data migrations
    'sekizai', #for javascript and css management
    #'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.flash',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    #'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.teaser',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    #'cms.plugins.video',
    'cms.plugins.twitter',
    'filer',
    'cmsplugin_filer_file',
    'cmsplugin_filer_folder',
    'cmsplugin_filer_image',
    'cmsplugin_filer_teaser',
    'cmsplugin_filer_video',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'PIL',

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
    },
    'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
    },
    'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    }
}
```

when i try to upload an image, in the clipboard section i don't have the thumbnail, but just an 'undefined' message:

[image]

and this is the runserver console while trying to upload:

```
[20/Oct/2012 15:15:56] "POST /admin/filer/clipboard/operations/upload/?qqfile=29708_1306856312320_7706073_n.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 248133
[20/Oct/2012 15:15:56] "GET /it/admin/filer/folder/unfiled_images/undefined HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[20/Oct/2012 15:15:56] "GET /it/admin/filer/folder/unfiled_images/undefined/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1739
```

Also, this is project filesystem:

```
cms1
├── cms1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── media
│   │   └── filer_public
│   │       └── 2012
│   │           └── 10
│   │               └── 20
│   │                   ├── 29708_1306856312320_7706073_n_1.jpg
│   │                   ├── 29708_1306856312320_7706073_n_2.jpg
│   │                   ├── 29708_1306856312320_7706073_n_3.jpg
│   │                   ├── 29708_1306856312320_7706073_n_4.jpg
│   │                   ├── 29708_1306856312320_7706073_n_5.jpg
│   │                   ├── 29708_1306856312320_7706073_n_6.jpg
│   │                   ├── 29708_1306856312320_7706073_n_7.jpg
│   │                   ├── 29708_1306856312320_7706073_n.jpg
│   │                   └── torrent-client-macosx.jpg
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── static
│   ├── static_auto
│   ├── static_manual
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── template_1.html
│   │   └── template_2.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── manage.py
```

So files are uploaded, but they are not accessible to cms. there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885312/undefined-uploads-using-django-cms-cmsplugin-filer-file-and-cmsplugin-filer-imag) here, but doens't help me so much. 
It would be very helpful any help on this issue to me.

Thanks, luke

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error because you installed PIL with out JPEG/PNG support.
you will need to install the following packages

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging  python-dev libjpeg8 libjpeg8-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
```

Then uninstall PIL `pip uninstall PIL`

I suggest installing pillow instead of PIL using `pip install pillow`.
make sure to read the log after installation, it should say that JPEG and PNG are supported

[image: Console Log]

Comment: i've already installed pillow instead of PIL, and i'm pretty sure that  i have installed also those libraries through apt-get. which log i have to check (i'm using local development runserver)?

Comment: I mean The log displayed in console when installing pillow using pip
you should see something like
*** TKINTER support not available (Tcl/Tk 8.5 libraries needed)
    --- JPEG support available
    --- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
    --- FREETYPE2 support available
    --- LITTLECMS support available

Comment: What django-filer version are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I had to uninstall and reinstall pillow and then worked fine with the additionals libraries that you mentioned.

Comment: if you're on windows use easy_install pillow, pip will install but won't work

Comment: OMG! Thanks you! It's was my first deploy with uwsgi and I think reason in bad config.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me - I had both PIL and Pillow installed, and the problem was happening when both are loaded, but only on certain VMs. I found that everything worked great on my local dev Mac and my local Virtualbox CentOS VM, but the error occurred on an Amazon CentOS 64 bit box.  I couldn't ever get it working with Pillow on all three (using Pillow 2.2.2 and PIL 1.1.7).

I took Pillow out of the requirements.txt, and instead only used PIL.  I use this chef recipe to do the installation of PIL first, and that works well on all Amazon and all tested boxes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
sudo ln -s -f /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s -f /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s -f /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather "old" question in Stackoverflow timespace, but I was having the exact same issue.

And [bazaretas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390674/bazaretas) pointed me in the right direction but I was missing a point in my setup.

I had installed Pillow instead of PIL, but one of my other requirements package had a dependency upon PIL (in its setup.py), and thus, pip installed PIL as well. But PIL has issue over distribute and virtualenv, so it did not grab the devel packages to have all format support.

The incriminated package was xhtml2pdf for me.

Check your dependency or find a way to install PIL beforehand in your venv (ie [here](http://www.sandersnewmedia.com/why/2012/04/16/installing-pil-virtualenv-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435016/install-pil-on-virtualenv-with-libjpeg) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485295/the-problem-with-installing-pil-using-virtualenv-or-buildout)).