# django filer plugin for image - undefined thumbnails

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm really new to Django CMS.

I created a virtual env, installed django cms, and I have two simple template with placeholders.

I have installed django filer for file, image and folder. It s working but when I upload an image ..the image is actually uploaded I can see in media folder but on the django interface the thumbnails are undefined.

I have installed `easy_thumbnails` but in the media folder I can't see the "filer_public_thumbnails" folder.

This may be similar problem to this:
[undefined uploads using django cms cmsplugin_filer_file and cmsplugin_filer_image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885312/undefined-uploads-using-django-cms-cmsplugin-filer-file-and-cmsplugin-filer-imag)

I understood the problem but I can't figure out how to solve i ...I have tried to create the directory manually but it doesn't work.

If I inspect the 'undefined" thumbnails window I have two error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Any tips please?

Comment: I don't know I start the project from scratch again and it works ..

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem disappear after this:  in settings.py:

```
USE_TZ = False
```

Reason: a bug in easy-thumbnails 1.0.3